# Multiple Update statements running slow in SQL Stored procedure

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

Please refer to the below SQL commands which is a part of the stored procedure. The stored procedure creates a temporary table named #TREPORT and then I perform following multiple updates on SODATE column.

The temporary table (#TREPORT) has about 1 million records and below statements are making performance slower. How can I improve it further?

@SDATE and @EDATE are parameters which is starting date and ending date.

Thanks in advance.

```
   UPDATE #TREPORT SET 
          SODATE  = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' where #TREPORT.SODATE is NULL

   UPDATE #TREPORT SET 
          SODATE  = (SELECT TOP 1 docdate from SO200 
          where SO200.NUMBORIG = #TREPORT.SOPNr 
          AND SO200.SOTYPE = '3' 
    --         AND 
    --DOCDATE is not null and DOCDATE >= '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@SDATE,101) +''
    --         and DOCDATE <= '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@EDATE,101) +''
      ) 
          where #TREPORT.SODATE = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' or #TREPORT.SODATE is NULL

   UPDATE #TREPORT SET 
          SODATE  = (SELECT TOP 1 docdate from SO100 
          where SO100.NUMBORIG = #TREPORT.SOPNr 
          AND SO100.SOTYPE = '3' 
    --         AND 
    --DOCDATE is not null and DOCDATE >= '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@SDATE,101) +''
    --         and DOCDATE is not null and DOCDATE <= '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@EDATE,101) +''
      ) 
      where #TREPORT.SODATE = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'  or #TREPORT.SODATE is NULL

   UPDATE #TREPORT SET 
          RowValue = 'C' where 
      (#TREPORT.SODATE < '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@SDATE,101) +''
          or #TREPORT.SODATE > '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@EDATE,101) +'')

   UPDATE #TREPORT SET 
          RowValue = 'D' where #TREPORT.SODATE  = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
          or #TREPORT.SODATE is NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large updates are best performed in batches.   See the solution here:

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/largeupdate/

As for combining your updates, your first update is completely superfluous because you're replacing NULL with a default value, and the other updates replace "NULL or {the default value}", so you could have just skipped the first one completely.

The other 4 updates could be combined into one with a CASE statement.

```
UPDATE #TREPORT SET SODATE=CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * from SO200 where SO200.NUMBORIG = #TREPORT.SOPNr AND SO200.SOTYPE = '3')
    THEN (SELECT TOP 1 docdate from SO200 
          where SO200.NUMBORIG = #TREPORT.SOPNr 
          AND SO200.SOTYPE = '3')
  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * from SO100 where SO100.NUMBORIG = #TREPORT.SOPNr AND SO100.SOTYPE = '3')
    THEN (SELECT TOP 1 docdate from SO100 
          where SO100.NUMBORIG = #TREPORT.SOPNr 
          AND SO100.SOTYPE = '3')
  ELSE '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
END
,  RowValue=CASE
  WHEN       (#TREPORT.SODATE < '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@SDATE,101) +''
          or #TREPORT.SODATE > '' +CONVERT(varchar(10),@EDATE,101) +'')
    THEN 'C'
  ELSE 'D'
END
where #TREPORT.SODATE = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' or #TREPORT.SODATE is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to know if I can merge these multiple updates into 1 or smaller UPDATE commands. I have update statement on SODATE field alone.